# Android SurfaceView not creating in Portrait Mode

Tags: android, layout, orientation, surfaceview

I've got a simple LinearLayout with a custom SurfaceView class and some buttons. Previously I had forced the orientation to Landscape in the Activity tag in the Manifest, however now I need to make it portrait. For some reason when I force the orientation portrait the SurfaceView isn't created. I tested the layout by just using a single FrameLayout and inside that a single instance of my SurfaceView class but still, it wouldn't create properly.

The error I get depends on what the first instance to the Thread within the SurfaceView is. Normally it's my UI thread in onCreate requesting a handle to the thread which causes a NullPointerException.

Any ideas why my code works in landscape but not portrait? Also it has the same issue if I don't select the orientation and then rotate it from landscape to portrait.

EDIT: Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <stu.test.project.DrawingSurface
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:id="@+id/drawingSurface"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">   
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonRow1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonRow2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the onCreate on the Activity that calls the surfaceView, the error is located on the last line where the handle to the Thread is retrieved

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.drawing_layout);  



        // Retrieve STATE and patient number from intent
        bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        STATE = bundle.getInt("state");
        patientString = bundle.getString("patientString");

        //retrieveViews();
        showButtons();

        System.out.println("IN ONCREATE");

        // Setup initial stuff if creating rather than resuming
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            System.out.println("IN ONCREATE AND NO SIS");
            switch(STATE){
            case STATE_DRAW:
                setupDraw();
                break;
            case STATE_LOAD:
                setupLoad();
                drawLoad();
                break;
            }       
        }

        /* Should put Else in here
         * to maybe resume data from savedInstanceState
         * rather than using onSurfaceCreated as do at moment
         */

        // Retrieve handle to thread
        mThread = drawingSurface.getThread();

      }
```

And here's the SurfaceView Class, not sure what is relevant so copied it all:

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private boolean _run;
private Object mPauseLock = new Object();  
private boolean mPaused;
private int STATE;
private static final int STATE_DRAW=1;
private static final int STATE_LOAD=2;
private static final int STATE_PAUSED=4;
private static final int STATE_RESUME_DRAWING=5;
private boolean finishDrawing;
private boolean startedDrawing=true;
private int resetCanvas=0;
private boolean threadRunning;
protected DrawThread thread;
boolean loaded;

public DrawingSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
}


class DrawThread extends  Thread{
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private List<DrawingPath> mDrawingPaths;
    private List<MyLine> mMyLines, backupLines;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        mDrawingPaths = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DrawingPath>());
        mMyLines = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MyLine>());
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public void setBackupLine(List<MyLine> l){
        backupLines = l;
        System.out.println("SETUP BACKLINE SIZE IS: "+backupLines.size());
    }

    // Two methods for your Runnable/Thread class to manage the Thread properly.
    public void onPause() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            // Only pause if not finished drawing, if finished want to exit thread
            if (!finishDrawing){
            mPaused = true;
            loaded=false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Set mPaused = true");
    }

    public void onResume() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = false;
            mPauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
        System.out.println("Set mPaused = false");
//            // Load the saved drawings or reload
//            if (STATE == STATE_DRAW)
//              setState(STATE_RESUME_DRAWING);
//            // If loading then dont change state and instead just restart thread
//            else if (STATE == STATE_LOAD){ 
////                resumeDrawing();
//              setRunning(true); 
//            }

    }

    public boolean needToWait(){
        return finishDrawing||mPaused;
    }

    public void setFinishDrawing(boolean b){
        finishDrawing=b;
    }

    public void setReset(int reset){
        resetCanvas=reset;
    }

    public void addMyLines(List<MyLine> lines){
        mMyLines = lines;
    }

    public void addDrawingPath(DrawingPath drawingPath){

        mDrawingPaths.add( drawingPath );
    }

    public int getSizeDrawingPaths(){
        return mDrawingPaths.size();
    }

    public void setLoadPaint(Paint p){
        mPaint =  p;
    }

    public DrawingPath getDrawingPath(int index){
        return mDrawingPaths.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {  
        while (_run){
            // Set variable for running
            threadRunning=true;
            Canvas canvas = null;

            // This code pauses the thread
            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                while (mPaused) {
                    try {                       
                        mPauseLock.wait();  
                        System.out.println("IN PAUSE LOOP");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            try{
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                // Split into DRAW and LOAD

                // DRAW IMAGE FROM PATHS
                if (STATE == STATE_DRAW){
                synchronized(mDrawingPaths) {
                    // If not finished drawing or resetthen draw onto canvas
                    if (!finishDrawing&&resetCanvas==0){
 //                         // Draw screen white
//                          if (startedDrawing){
//                              startedDrawing=false;
//                              canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
//                              System.out.println("DRAWING CANVAS WHITE");
//                              
//                          }
                        doDraw(canvas);
                    }
                    }
                    if (resetCanvas>0){
                        System.out.println("Resetting canvas");
                        if (canvas!=null)
                            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);  
                        resetCanvas--;
                    }                      
                }

                // DRAW IMAGE FROM POINTS
                else if (STATE == STATE_LOAD){
                    doLoad(canvas, mMyLines);
                    // Then close the thread
                    setRunning(false);
                }

                // IF RESUMING FROM DRAWING PAUSE
                else if (STATE == STATE_RESUME_DRAWING){
                    if (!loaded) {
                        doLoad(canvas, backupLines);
                        System.out.println("DID LOAD OF RESUME");
                        setState(STATE_DRAW);
                        loaded=true;
                        //setRunning(false);
                    }
                }
            }
             finally {
                if (canvas!=null){
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }                   
        } // While run
    }

    public void doDraw(Canvas c){
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Iterator i = mDrawingPaths.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()){
            final DrawingPath drawingPath = (DrawingPath) i.next();
            if (c==null)
                System.out.println("CANVAS IS NULL");
            else if (drawingPath.path==null)
                System.out.println("PATH IS NULL");
            else if (drawingPath.paint==null)
                System.out.println("PAINT IS NULL");
            if (c!=null) // Only draw to canvas if it isnt null
                c.drawPath(drawingPath.path, drawingPath.paint);
        }
    }

    public void doLoad(Canvas c, List<MyLine> lines){
        // Loop through the List of lines
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Iterator i = lines.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            // Get the current line
            final MyLine lineIt = (MyLine) i.next();
            // Create new array of floating points to hold the PointFs from MyLine to draw
            float prevX=0, prevY=0;
            for (int j=0;j<lineIt.getSize()-1;j=j+2){  
                 if (c==null)
                    System.out.println("CANVAS IS NULL");
                if (j!=0&&c!=null){
                    c.drawLine(prevX, prevY, lineIt.getPoint(j).x, lineIt.getPoint(j+1).y, mPaint);
                }
                prevX = lineIt.getPoint(j).x;
                prevY = lineIt.getPoint(j+1).y;
            }   
        }
    }

        public void remove(int i) {
            mDrawingPaths.remove(i);

        }

        public void clearAllPaths(){
            mDrawingPaths.clear();
        }

        public void setState(int s){
            STATE = s;
        }

}


public void addDrawingPath (DrawingPath drawingPath){
    thread.addDrawingPath(drawingPath);
}

public int getSizeDrawingPaths(){
    return thread.getSizeDrawingPaths();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,  int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // only create thread if doesnt exist
    if (!threadRunning){
            thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.setFinishDrawing(false);
            thread.setReset(2); // Set reset to colour screen white
            thread.start();
    }
//      // Resuming is handled in DrawingActivity's onPause override
//      else {  
//          thread.onResume();
//      }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean retry = true;
    // If finished drawing then close thread
    // Else just want to pause thread
//        if (finishDrawing){
//          thread.setRunning(false);
//          while (retry) { 
//                try {
//                    thread.join();
//                    retry = false;
//                    threadRunning = false; // Set threadRunning to false so creates new thread when rejoins
//                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                    // we will try it again and again...
//                }
//            }         
//        }
//        else {
//          thread.onPause();
//          System.out.println("Paused thread in SurfaceDestroyed");
//          System.out.println("threadRunning is :"+threadRunning);
//        }


}

    public void remove(int i) {
        thread.remove(i);

    }

    public void getDrawingPath(int i){
        thread.getDrawingPath(i);
    }

    public void clearAllPaths(){
        thread.clearAllPaths();
    }

    public void resetScreen(){
        thread.setReset(2);
    }

    public void addMyLines(List<MyLine> lines){
        thread.addMyLines(lines);
    }

    public void finishDrawing(){
        thread.setFinishDrawing(true);
    }

    public DrawThread getThread(){
        return thread;
    }

    public void resumeDrawing(){
        thread.setFinishDrawing(false);
    }

    public void setState(int s){
        thread.setState(s);
    }

    public void setLoadPaint(Paint p){
        thread.setLoadPaint(p);
    }

    public void pauseThread(){
        thread.onPause();
    }

    public void resumeThread(){
        thread.onResume();
    }

    public boolean getThreadRunning(){
        return threadRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code, so we can see what the problem might be?

Comment: Posted my layout, part of the Activity and all of the SurfaceView code.

Comment: The previous Activity, the one that called this activity with SurfaceView is also forced landscape. I found that if I allowed the previous Activity to be portrait, then when this activity started up the SurfaceView worked as required. So the problem is somewhere within the Screen changing orientation in the launching of this Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the same layout file for portrait and landscape?

I had a similar sounding buglet today where I had the surfaceView in the portrait layout file but not in the landscape layout file. For some reason it ran but when I rotated the device surfaceCreated|Changed|Destroyed no longer occurred. Rotating back and everything was happy again.